# PAUSE the screen

Tags: android, database, sqlite, screen

i need to pause my screen for a while because i have a database to show..... i show my database per row to a xml layout... The problem is the xml layout always show the most bottom from my database... That's why i believe if ican stop the screen for a while i'll be able to see the other row from the layout...

Here is my code :

```
public void get() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String count = bundle.getString("x");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor z = db.getAllList();
        if (z.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                DisplayList(z,count);
            } while (z.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
}

public void DisplayList(Cursor z, String count) {
    String b = z.getString(1);
    if (count.equals(b)) {
        /*Toast.makeText(this,
                "Id      : " + z.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "Product : " + z.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "Brand   : " + z.getString(2) + "\n" +
                "Place   : " + z.getString(3) + "\n" +
                "Date    : " + z.getString(4) + "\n" +
                "Price   : Rp. " + z.getString(5),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        TextView X = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a); 
        TextView Y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b); 
        TextView Z = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.c); 
        TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.d); 
        TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.e);  
        String a = z.getString(1);
        String f = z.getString(2);
        String c = z.getString(3);
        String d = z.getString(4);
        String e = z.getString(5);
        X.setText("Product     : " + a);
        Y.setText("Brand        : " + f);
        Z.setText("Bought at  : " + c);
        A.setText("Date          : " + d);
        B.setText("Price         : Rp. " + e);
    }
}
```

my plan is to pause right after the display list :

```
do {
DisplayList(z,count);
    //here
} while (z.moveToNext());
```

any ideas ??? i tried thread.sleep but no use......

Like this :

```
do {
DisplayList(z,count);
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
} while (z.moveToNext());
```

Comment: You mean you want to overwrite the TextViews for every row after some seconds. Can't you show all data in listview?

Comment: Yes, u got what i mean but the problem is... the listview are to small .... as u can see i want show the 5 informations simultaneously

Comment: Ok. got it. How did you use Thread.sleep? Can you show that code?

Comment: I edited text above.... i forgot exactly how i did it but it's something similar like that.... The result is the screen black (in transition from one layout to another) for a while and still the most bottom db showed

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It might work.

```
do {
        Thread myThread = new Thread() 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    super.run();
                    sleep(3000)  //Delay of 3 seconds
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage();
                } finally {
                      DisplayList(z,count);
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
   } while (z.moveToNext());
```

Comment: I tried... but stuck in the line of public void run().... X sign in that line.. dunno why.. said bout enum and @expected... any idea ???

Comment: What is the error when you hover mouse on red line? @CharlesLynch Can you copy that exactly?

Comment: This is what i got ...                                              Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
  EnumHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
 - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

Comment: That's strange. I never had this problem. Sorry, I can't understand